# Doesn't `for(;;)` evaluate to false as it is an empty statement?

Tags: c, for-loop

`for(;;)` statement is an empty statement. Though being an empty condition, compiler should treat it as `null` statement which is equivalent to `0` , i.e FALSE. Therefore, according to me, it should not get evaluated.

But to my surprise, compiler sends the true signal.

Kindly explain.

Comment: for(;0;){} would (I suspect) do what you expect.... consider for(;;) to be idiomatic and not try to parse it.

Comment: Why those negative votes? Looks like a legit question

Comment: It is neither an empty nor a null statement, and it isn't equivalent to either 0, FALSE, 1, or `true`, and it isn't sent by the compiler as 'the true signal' either, whatever that may mean.

Comment: I am sorry.
I might have used wrong language here.
I wanted to talk about the conditional block in for loop only.
What i already know is- compiler treats an empty (no condition) conditional block as "TRUE" and from all these answers to my question, that made no difference.
If i am wrong. please explain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C standard states that if the condition is present, then it should treated as if it had a non-zero value.

> 6.8.5.3, p2 The for statement for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 )
>
> Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. **An omitted
>   expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.**

(emphasis mine)

This is inconsistent with `while` loop though as the conditional expression can't be left empty in a while loop. But that's how C is on many aspects :)

Answer (score 4):

The Infinite Loop:

A loop becomes infinite loop if a condition never becomes false. The for loop is traditionally used for this purpose. Since none of the three expressions that form the for loop are required, you can make an endless loop by leaving the conditional expression empty.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

   for( ; ; )
   {
      printf("This loop will run forever.\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

When the conditional expression is absent, it is assumed to be true. You may have an initialization and increment expression, but C programmers more commonly use the for(;;) construct to signify an infinite loop.
Happy Coding :-)

Comment: It looks odd, it draws your eye, and so is obvious. This is known as an *idiom*.

Answer (score 2):

A null statement is not equivalent to `0` or `false`. Omitting all expressions from `for` loop make it an equivalent to `while(1)`.

When the conditional statement in `for` loop is empty, then you need to specify that in loop body.